# How to apply justify content only for first row using bootstrap4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I am looking for a solution where the dynamically generated rows of a div are aligned center but only for the first row, I mean if it is one row and the elements in a row are less than specified bootstrap class property `col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12`. then align them center but when elements are more and they start filling the second row then the second-row elements should start from the left not from the center.

Is there any direct keyword for this or do I have to write some logic? Below is the  code:

```css
.col-3 {
  padding-top: .75rem;
  padding-bottom: .75rem;
  background-color: rgba(86, 61, 124, .15);
  border: 1px solid rgba(86, 61, 124, .2);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384- 
     Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-3">1</div>
    <div class="col-3">2</div>
    <div class="col-3">3</div>
    <div class="col-3">4</div>
    <div class="col-3">5</div>
    <div class="col-3">6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your demo should probably have more than one row, since that's a critical aspect of your question. Also, rows can't (shouldn't) also be columns, and vice versa. Don't put both component's classes on one element. Please fix that and add at least one more row so we can see the actual situation.

Answer (score 1):

Use `margin-right: auto;` or the `.me-auto` class on the last `.col-3` child.

```css
.col-3 {
  padding-top: .75rem;
  padding-bottom: .75rem;
  background-color: rgba(86, 61, 124, .15);
  border: 1px solid rgba(86, 61, 124, .2);
}

.row>.col-3:last-child {
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384- 
     Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container mb-4">
  <h4> w/ margin-right: auto; or .me-auto on last child</h4>
  <div class="row col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-3">1</div>
    <div class="col-3">2</div>
    <div class="col-3">3</div>
    <div class="col-3">4</div>
    <div class="col-3">5</div>
    <div class="col-3">6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also just remove `justify-content-center`. See notes in the snippet.

```css
.col-3 {
  padding-top: .75rem;
  padding-bottom: .75rem;
  background-color: rgba(86, 61, 124, .15);
  border: 1px solid rgba(86, 61, 124, .2);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384- 
     Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container mb-4">
  <h4> w/ justify-content-center </h4>
  <div class="row col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-3">1</div>
    <div class="col-3">2</div>
    <div class="col-3">3</div>
    <div class="col-3">4</div>
    <div class="col-3">5</div>
    <div class="col-3">6</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container mb-4">
  <h4> w/o justify-content-center </h4>
  <div class="row col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-3">1</div>
    <div class="col-3">2</div>
    <div class="col-3">3</div>
    <div class="col-3">4</div>
    <div class="col-3">5</div>
    <div class="col-3">6</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container mb-4">
  <h4> full width w/ justify-content-center </h4>
  <div class="row col-sm-12 justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-3">1</div>
    <div class="col-3">2</div>
    <div class="col-3">3</div>
    <div class="col-3">4</div>
    <div class="col-3">5</div>
    <div class="col-3">6</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container mb-4">
  <h4> full width w/o justify-content-center but container has max-width, resembles first fully populated row to be centered </h4>
  <div class="row col-sm-12">
    <div class="col-3">1</div>
    <div class="col-3">2</div>
    <div class="col-3">3</div>
    <div class="col-3">4</div>
    <div class="col-3">5</div>
    <div class="col-3">6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the relpy @Kameron, sorry if i was not able to convey my question well. The question is " How to use justiy-content-center only for first row from second row elemets should start from left not from center."

Comment: @sam See edits.

Comment: Hi, I have tried the edited code but the justify content center rule is not applied to the elemets. I just gave 2 elements according to the rule they should be in the center but they are starting from left. I think instead of last-child, is there an option to give all the childs startin from nth child will have margin-right:auto

Comment: @isherwood Updated. I only used custom CSS only to target `:last-child` assuming that the children count was dynamic.